# Lightning: automatically put a component to layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, automation

I'd like to know if it is possible to add a Lightning Component to a Lightning Page (say, default Opportunity page in Lightning) **automatically**, i.e. using some API? For example, in Salesforce classic we can change a page layout using Metadata API. Is there anything like that in Lightning?